# Top area of a e commerce website. Popular way or Innovative way.?

Tags: navigation, search, e-commerce, product-design

Mostly we see one common way of presenting the top area of e-commerce websites as below. I have heard most technical people complain about this.

[image]

---

[image]

They say their should be more exciting way or users will think this is just another e commerce website.

What do you think about this matter. Should it be the traditional way or there should be a exciting factor?

### This is something I designed recently. I got above comments for this.

[image]

Comment: I may be being dumb today, but I don't see any essential difference between your design and the others... all three have a basket, search bar and some menu items. Yours is less "cluttered" than certainly the AliExpress one, but the overall approach seems the same...

Comment: @TripeHound Indeed no. Ideally the same but simple. That's why I got those comments that my design is missing the magic portion.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, there's nothing wrong with your design... it's fairly clean and uncluttered, and looks "sufficiently like" an e-commerce site that I'm not wondering where things are. If it _were_ totally different, then as Deniz says, this may confuse users more.

Comment: This question is off-topic as answers will be primarily opinion based. "Which is the better of these two slightly different options?" comes down to what people prefer. The best design for any screen is the one that helps users fulfill their shopping goals so that site owners meet their business goals. This is precisely the kind of thing you should be A/B testing. One good test is worth a thousand expert opinions.

Comment: Your user will expect to find particular elements in certain places (like the search bar in the centre and the cart to the right). Everyone does this because it's an accepted pattern that most users are comfortable using. Even Amazon, who spend vast amounts of money on streamlining the process, use this configuration because it works - Focus your innovation on the way you display products or on the service you give - find somewhere you'll get value from innovating and rather than innovating for the sake of innovation and at the cost of sales.

Comment: @TripeHound cleanness & simplicity is what I wanted to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: @dennislees What I wanted to clarify and emphasis is the fact weather we should we offer innovative and exciting look and feel than the conventional e commerce layouts for the users. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Totally agree with your perception.

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason that e-commerce sites look like each other as they respond to the basic users need: quickly find what they are looking for and as most of the businesses copy each other's best practices, this becomes a very usual journey for many users.

What your target audience thinks must be your real question. Is there a validation that your version is more exciting than the previous headers? All I can see you just used a vertical menu instead of a horizontal one.

Comment: I'm also a believe that a familiar user journey can work in a better way. So that they know where to find whatever they need.
My design here is the most simplest one I could develop. Obviously that is exciting. 
I believe we don't need to put icing on this. Simplicity will do a lot.